# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier cannot retrieve identified cell in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I created a `UITableViewController` of dynamic prototype cells in the `Storyboard` that can show 3 different custom cells

[image]

But I am getting `*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /` which theoretically means that the `reuseidentifier` I am trying to use in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` does not exist but as I am sure I have defined it in my storyboard.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    HomeOverviewItem *item = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"cell at %@",indexPath);
    if([item propCellType] == HomeOverviewItem_HEADER){
        CellHomeHeader *cell = (CellHomeHeader *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_header"];

        cell.propLabelName.text = item.propName;
        cell.propLabelCntReqs.text = item.propRequestCnt;
        cell.propLabelCntDays.text = item.propDaysCnt;

        NSLog(@"returning header cell %@",cell);
        return cell;
    }else if([item propCellType] == HomeOverviewItem_ITEM1){
        CellHomeItem1 *cell = (CellHomeItem1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_item1"];

        cell.propLabelName.text = item.propName;
        cell.propLabelCntReqs.text = item.propRequestCnt;
        cell.propLabelCntDays.text = item.propDaysCnt;

        NSLog(@"returning item1 cell %@",cell);
        return cell;
    }else{
        CellHomeItem2 *cell = (CellHomeItem2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_item2"];

        cell.propLabelName.text = item.propName;
        cell.propLabelCntReqs.text = item.propRequestCnt;
        cell.propLabelCntDays.text = item.propDaysCnt;

        NSLog(@"returning item2 cell %@",cell);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I will add this image below to make sure that identifier is the same to what I am using on my code
[image]

Error:

[image]

Where could I possibly go wrong?

Comment: @rob, if you can see on the sidebar, the labels on the cells under the table view is the identifier I used to define for them

Comment: so, I can safely assume that I am using the same identifier in both of my storyboard and my code

Comment: I've added an edit to show that I am using the same identifier

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. This is going to sound crazy, but do you have more than one table view controller in your storyboard? Are you 100% sure you don't have the wrong scene selected? Also, make sure you don't have any spaces at the end of the the "identifier" field in the storyboard. This is very curious. It's likely to be something crazy like that. Also, how did you instantiate this scene? (There's no segue into the scene, so I wonder if it was instantiated incorrectly (e.g. using `[[HomeLeaves alloc] init]` rather than `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:...]`.)

Comment: This badly happens mostly for identifier. One more thing under identity inspector did you provide class name?

Comment: @Rob, yes I am 100% sure that I am using the correct scene via logging... And yeah I also made sure no trailing spaces... I used the storyboard to instantiate the tableviewcontroller

Comment: @Amit89, yes class name is already provided and connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem many thanks to the hint given by Bob....

I want to post this answers for future devs who might also experience this problem.

The one causing this problem is how I instantiate the viewcontroller.

for this case, **NEVER** instantiate the viewcontrollerv via `alloc` then `init`

instantiate the view using `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerID"]`

Answer (score 0):

I bet your call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is returning `nil` because initially there are no cells to be dequeued (from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:): *A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier or nil if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.*). Use 
[- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) as this will always return a valid cell.

Comment: Even if he uses the rendition with the `NSIndexPath`, it will still fail if the identifiers don't match up precisely. And given what he's shared thus far, the problem is undoubtedly a mismatch between the storyboard identifier supplied in IB and that which he referenced in his code. Simply using this other rendition is unlikely to help him.

Comment: yes, @Rob is right. I've already tried that but same error. Thanks for the answer anyway